# Update Intel-microcode with amd CPU

Tags: apt, firmware

Why does apt propose an update of Intel-microcode on my computer with an AMD cpu (Ryzen 7 2700X), and should I do this update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have no fear.   Apt is only proposing an update of a package already installed in your distribution.   Its contents will never be used, in your case.